# issue in role based authorization in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

i am trying to implement authentication and authorization in c# project.

authentication is working fine.

while trying to achieve role based authorization like this->

```
[System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles = UserRoles.Admin)]
[ApiController]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/[controller]")]
public class StudentsController : ControllerBase

.
.
.
```

i am able to access this controller even with a `User` role.

i have used this inside my `HttpGet` method

```
var isAdmin = User.IsInRole(UserRoles.Admin);
```

this returns `false`.

what could be the issue?

if you need any other code, please let me know i can add it.

i have followed this tutorial
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-authentication-and-authorization-in-net-6-0-with-identity-framework/

i am working with `.net 6.0`

Comment: `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` is for **WebForms** - not ASP.NET Core. In fact, your shouldn't even _compile_ - what's going on? ([ASP.NET Core uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0)).

Comment: that works. thanks! but i dont know why it was compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I was using wrong import for `Authorize` (`System.Web.Http.Authorize` attribute is for WebForms).

After using import from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` issue was fixed.